# node-postgres: A query with "where in/any" isn't executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have a JavaScript application running on NodeJS. It basically checks an API every 3 seconds and writes some stuff into a Postgres database. I am using [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/) to interact with the database.

**CODE**

```
setInterval(dataObserver, 3000);

function dataObserver() {
  request(stateUrl, function (err, statusCode, data) {
    if (err) {
      log.message(data, "debug");
      log.message('0: ' + err.message, "error");
    } else {
      try {
        fightData = parseJson(data);
      } catch (error) {
        log.message('1: ' + error, "error");
      }

      matchCheck = fightData.remaining;
      statusCheck = fightData.status;

      setMatchType();
      setMatchStatus();

      if (matchStatus != oldStatus && matchType != 'Exhibition') {
        oldStatus = matchStatus;
        let redFighter = fightData.p1name;
        let blueFighter = fightData.p2name;
        let redBets = fightData.p1total;
        let blueBets = fightData.p2total;

        switch (matchStatus) {
          case 'open':
            break;
          case 'locked':
            break;
          case 'redWon':
            checkDatabase(redFighter, blueFighter);
            setTimeout(function () {
              addMatch(redFighter, blueFighter, redBets, blueBets, redFighter);
              addMatchResults(redFighter, blueFighter);
              addFavor(redFighter, blueFighter, redBets, blueBets);
            }, 10000);
            break;
          case 'blueWon':
            checkDatabase(redFighter, blueFighter);
            setTimeout(function () {
              addMatch(redFighter, blueFighter, redBets, blueBets, blueFighter);
              addMatchResults(blueFighter, redFighter);
              addFavor(redFighter, blueFighter, redBets, blueBets);
            }, 10000);
            break;
          default:
            log.message('Unknown match status!', "error");
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  })
};

// this is where the issue is
function checkDatabase(redFighter, blueFighter) {
  console.log('checking database!');
  db.query('select name from fightertable where name = any($1)', [[redFighter, blueFighter]], (err, res) => {
    console.log('we are inside check database query');
    if (err) {
      log.message('2: ' + err.message, "error");
    } else if (typeof res.rows[0] == 'undefined' && typeof res.rows[1] == 'undefined') {
      addFighterName(redFighter, blueFighter);
    } else if (res.rows[0].name == redFighter) {
      addFighterName(blueFighter);
    } else if (res.rows[0].name == blueFighter) {
      addFighterName(redFighter);
    } else {
      log.message('Database check failed!', "error");
    }
  });
}
```

This line never gets executed:

```
console.log('we are inside check database query');
```

But this one `console.log('checking database!');` does!

And I'm not sure why. I have followed the [official Wiki](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/FAQ#11-how-do-i-build-a-where-foo-in--query-to-find-rows-matching-an-array-of-values) on this, so the query should be Ok.

**UPDATE**:

I went ahead and used Knex as suggested, but it still doesn't work, in the exact same place! Unless I'm screwing up the knex syntax, but again I followed the docs. Line 3 & 4 are not hit.

[image]

Comment: Try it with http://knexjs.org/

Comment: @yeya see update added to question. I went ahead and used Knex as suggested.

Comment: Do you success to run any query at all? Try listen to errors.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors, and yep, a simple query like `select 1` works fine.

Comment: Works from node? With knex?

Comment: Yep, here's a test `insert` that I'm doing. https://imgur.com/B68NVqf (query run on line 19) and results are in the pane above.